# Modeling conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Problem:

> We are given three coins: one has heads in both faces, the second has tails in both faces, and the third has a head in one face and a tail in the other. We choose a coin at random, toss it, and the result is heads. What is the probability that the opposite face is tails?

Solution:

> If $p = P(\text{Two headed coin was chosen | Heads came up}) = \displaystyle{\frac{\frac 13}{\frac 12} = \frac 23}$, then the probability that the opposite face is tails is $1 − p = \displaystyle{\frac 13}$.

New to probability, would like to see how this solution works in more detail.

My questions:

1.The sample space is $\{HH, HT, TT\}$. The condition that heads came up refers to the elements $\{HH, HT\}$ and the fact that two headed coin was chosen refers to $\{HH\}$. We want the probability of $\{HH, HT\} \cap \{HH\} = \{HH\}$. The probability of choosing $HH$ is $\displaystyle{\frac 13}$ by Uniform Probability Law. Is this correct?

2. When we calculate that $P(\text{Heads came up}) = \displaystyle{\frac 12}$, what's the sample space? Is it $\{H, T\}$ or $\{HH, HT, TT\}$? Thanks.

**edit**:

I think I finally understand how to model the sample space here.

Coin toss is a sequential experiment and so the order matters. For example, $HT$ is different from $TH$.

Our sample space is $\{H_1H_2, H_2H_1, T_1T_2, T_2T_1, TH, HT\}$.

Thus

$P(\text{two headed coin was selected $\cap$ heads came up(in the first toss)}) = P(\{H_1H_2, H_2H_1\}) = \frac 26 = \frac 13$

by the uniform probability law.

$P(\text{heads came up(in the first toss)}) = P(\{H_1H_2, H_2H_1, HT\}) = \frac 36 = \frac 12$ by the uniform probability law.

Comment: Hint: think about your sample space a bit more. There are two steps - first you select a coin and second you flip it The sample spaces you have written ${HH, HT, TT}$ only captures the first step.

Comment: @roundsquare, Just to be clear, you're talking about the second question, correct? If the heads came up, then the chosen coins are $HH$ or $HT$ and so the sample space must be $\{HH, HT\}$. Is that correct?

Comment: In general, the sample space relates to the situation, not a specific question about it. In your case, the sample space can be written as $\{(HH, H), (HT, H), (HT, T), (TT, T)\}$ but these are _not_ equi-probable (I'm writing (HT, T) to mean "the HT coin is picked and the outcome of the flip is T"). Once you have the probability space properly defined and the probabilities of each element of the space, you can jump on the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question 1 you can apply Bayes' theorem by noting that the event you are after is the same as having chosen the coin with both a H and T face, given that you tossed a H:

$$P(\text{coin is HT}|\text{toss H}) = \frac{P(\text{toss H} | \text{coin is HT}) \, P(\text{coin is HT})}{P(\text{toss H})}$$ and plugging in the appropriate values.

For your question 2 (i.e. the denominator in the above) you can use the Law of Total Probability (LOTP) to partition up the sample space:

$$P(\text{toss H}) = P(\text{toss H} | \text{coin is HH})P(\text{coin is HH}) + P(\text{toss H} | \text{coin is HT})P(\text{coin is HT}) + P(\text{toss H} | \text{coin is TT})P(\text{coin is TT})$$

and evaluating the probabilities.